# How to make a history of my var (Math.random)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with my code, i wanna see my passed 4 generated number (Math.random), on a history box, but these numbers show out the same. Is there a way to delay a var?

I have tried putting var in order, but this makes no delay.

my html:

```
    <div class="text-position-history">
        <div class="text-style-history">
            <p id="historyT"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

My javascript:

```
var green = 0;
var red = 0;

function odds(){

    var result = Math.random();

    if (result < 0.5)
    {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        green++;
        document.getElementById('greenT').innerHTML = "Times you survived: " + " " + green;

    }
    else{
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        red++;
        document.getElementById('redT').innerHTML = "Times you died: " + " " + red;
    }

    document.getElementById('resultT').innerHTML = "Guessed number: " + " " + result;

    var history1 = result;
    var history2 = history1;
    var history3 = history2;

    document.getElementById('historyT').innerHTML = "Guessed number: " + " " + result + " " + history1 + " " + history2 + " " + history3;


}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You will have to maintain an array of values. `var history1 = result;` will just assign same value to it

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create an array and then append the new values of result to the array after you call `Math.random()`?

```
var resultHistory = new Array();

var result = Math.random();
resultHistory.push(result);
```

Then print out the array later on.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use array of numbers?

```js
var _history = [];

function toHTMLElement(historyNode)
{
  var node = document.createElement("div");
  node.innerHTML = historyNode.text;
  node.style.background = historyNode.win?'green':'red';
  return node;
}

function renderHistory()
{
  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  result.innerHTML = "";
  _history.forEach(function(e){
    result.appendChild(toHTMLElement(e));
  });
}

document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  _history.push((Math.random()>0.5)?{win: true, text: 'You win'}:{win: false, text: 'You lose'});
  if (_history.length > 3) _history.shift();
  renderHistory();
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var green = 0;
var red = 0;

function odds(){

    var result = Math.random();

    if (result < 0.5)
    {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        green++;
        document.getElementById('greenT').innerHTML = "Times you survived: " + " " + green;

    }
    else{
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        red++;
        document.getElementById('redT').innerHTML = "Times you died: " + " " + red;
    }

    document.getElementById('resultT').innerHTML = "Guessed number: " + " " + result;

    var myList = [result, result, result];

    var history1 = myList.shift();

    var history2 = myList.shift();

    var history3 = myList.shift();

    document.getElementById('historyT').innerHTML = "Guessed numbesr: " + " " + history1 + " " + history2 + " " + history3;

}
```

This still gives the same result?

Answer (score -1):

I think actually changing the order of your history vars should fix it.
Change them to

```
    var history3 = history2;
    var history2 = history1;
  var history1 = result;
```

Right now you are overwritung everything to results because:

var history1 = result
var history2 = history1 (history1 is already referring to result by now)

Comment: Nope. That won't fix anything. This will assign undefined